# TabBar disappears after Segue (Swift - Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I wanna know how can i perform a segue from a normal `UIViewController` to my `UIViewcontroller`(with a tab bar) while still keeping the tab bar intact/visible. Do look at the image attached for a better reference.

P.S: I tried unWindSegue but it doesn't resolve it because i don't want to load my 2nd `UIViewController` first before i perform the segue.

PickACardController

```
import UIKit

class PickCardController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button3: UIButton!
    var returnValue: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "tokens")
    var returnValue2: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "userScore")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dissapear") == 1)
        {
            button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "wildcardbackingglassesdarken-3x.png"), for: .normal)
            button1.isEnabled = false
        }
        if (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dissapear2") == 1)
        {
            button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "wildcardbackingbikini-3x.png"), for: .normal)
            button2.isEnabled = false
        }
        if (UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dissapear3") == 1)
        {
            button3.setImage(UIImage(named: "wildcardbackingbottomdarken-3x.png"), for: .normal)
            button3.isEnabled = false
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    @IBAction func Button1(_ sender: Any) {
        var i: Int = 0
        let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1
        i = Int(randomNumber)

        let alert = AlertController(title: "Congratualations", message: "You earned \(i) tokens!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.setTitleImage(UIImage(named: "token"))
        // Add actions
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Let's See!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
                    self.returnValue = self.returnValue + i;
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(self.returnValue, forKey:"tokens")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: nil)
                    }))
            if (returnValue != 30){
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue Playing", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:    { (action) in
                    self.returnValue = self.returnValue + i;
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(self.returnValue, forKey:"tokens")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "continue", sender: self)
                    }))
            }
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey:"dissapear")
    }
```

TokenController

```
import UIKit

class TokenController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tokens: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var minus1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var minus2: UIButton!
    var returnValue: Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "tokens")
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tokens?.text = "x\(returnValue)"
    }
```

[image]

Comment: If you are willing to use a UITabBarController then you should first go through [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html)

Comment: Write some code, I don't think you can do this only by segues.

Comment: Do not Directly segue to VC2 You need to set segue to tabBar Controller and need to maintain some checks there and set Vc2 As Main Root in TabbAr as setSelectedIndex feature of TabBar Available by Default

Comment: @iOSGeek so u're saying i can only set my vc2 as my first tab bar view right

Comment: @FahriAzimov i don't really have any codes to show, its just empty view controllers with a IB button function.

Comment: Use unwind segue to go back to the previous view controller, and in the method of unwind segue, switch selected index of tabbarcontroller, like: `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0` (in your case). That should do the job.

Comment: No, suppose you have 2 segue A and B , Now when Segue A is Executed you need to show VC1 of Tab as Root and when Segue B is Executed You need to set VC2 as Root , So For ex. lets take a Struct with variable String CurrentVC : String? Now when Segue A is Executed update CurrentVC String to A and when control reach to Tabbar set VC1 as Root with setSelectedIndex and When Segue B Update CurrentVC as B and When Control reaches to tabBar setSelectedIndex to index of VC2

Comment: @FahriAzimov unwindSegue doesn't really solve me issue because i'm trying to pass data back to my 2nd vc as well.

Comment: u know what guys, give me a moment, let me update this qn with my codes first

Comment: Ok i just updated my codes. as u can see from my PickACard VC(1stVC), once i tap a card, an alert will prompt 2 alert actions showing "Lets See" & "Continue Playing". if a user taps on "Lets See". it will segue to my TokenController(2nd vc) which is a part of a TabBar

Comment: I tried using unwindSegue but the userdefaults data could not be passed to my TokenController. i need to load my TokenController first before user defaults can actually be passed.

Comment: Guys i would really appreciate it if y'all can help me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourTabbarController") as! UITabBarController
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then:

```
vc.selectedIndex = indexOfYourTokenVc in tabbar
```

I hope it may help.

Comment: It seems like you didn't understand the problem. Solution you have posted will not solve the issue.

Comment: oh sorry... yeah.. so then he has to make segue to tabbar controller and make selected the vc he wants to show.. im right ?

Comment: @junaidUmeryup thats right, i wanna show one of the view controller from tabbar

Comment: what does it do? is it my pickacard vc will segue back to my uitabbarcontroller and then it will actually move to my tokenvc index?

Comment: @junaidUmer let's say tokenvc index is 2 so the code shld be "vc.selectedindex = 2 in UITabBar" ?

Comment: @Kinja do this 
  vc.selectedindex = 2. 
before or after 
self.present

Comment: it says "Use of unresolved identifier 'vc''" when i put vc.selectedindex = 2

Comment: yes off course it will say because you are doing this in presenting vc's didload where this variable vc doesnt exist..

Comment: u r doing segue with storyboard?

Comment: @junaidUmer oh yea shoot, i haven't assign my segue with storyboard yet. could u tell me how can i do that again? I'm still quite stiff in swift

Comment: wait nvm let me try and figure it out first

Comment: you have to do segue from your VC to tabBarController in story board...
 then in your vc 
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let tabbar = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        tabbar.selectedIndex = 2
    }

Comment: @junaidUmer sorry just to cfm again, this line of code(https://ibb.co/gScfDm) shld be at my vc to tabbarcontroller?

Comment: yes it should work in this way too... 
you can add 
vc.selectedIndex = 2 
before presenting vc

Comment: @junaidUmer sry i meant shld be at my vc or my tabbarcontroller?

Comment: should be in your vc from where you want to navigate to another screen

Comment: @junaidUmer idk why but it keeps crashing when i segue from my VC to my UITabBarController. do i need to assign storyboard ID to the controllers?

Comment: yes you should have storyboard id assigned to your tabbar

Comment: @junaidUmer and the storyboardID is based on my segue identifier right?

Comment: @junaidUmer thanks so much bro! it works like a charm. sorry to keep asking u nonsensical questions and taking up a lot of your time!

Comment: @Kinja happy coding bro :)